# Get and Set Function Inquiries

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Variable{
private:
string name;
public:
//This is my second question
    //
void setName(string x){
    name = x;
}
string getName(){
    return name;
}
};
int main(){
Variable Voject;
Voject.setName("Hello");
cout << Voject.getName() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

First of all the code is working perfectly. Unfortunately, when I was watching the tutorial the dude didn't specifically told the reason why you should put all variables in the class as a private class(he says that it is a bad mannerism on a programmer and you should never put a variable in a public class). Please give me an explanation on that.

Another question is when you want to grab the variables in the private class you should set and get the variables. So should you really put the name of the function setName and getName? or is it just to be easily remembered.
PS. Im a Newbie so please put the answers as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Getters and setters aren't really idiomatic in C++, it's more common to just make the members public. The purpose of getters and setters is to allow a decoupling of a value from its affect on an object allowing more complex code if needed, to maintain consistent state for example.

For some interesting commentary on the utility of getters and setters in C++ see [Getting Abstractions](http://www.drdobbs.com/getting-abstractions/184401805). TL;DR: getters and setters are only a touch better than public variables, try to use a higher level of abstraction instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Private Variables

   You don't want other program to set your variable freely, which might cause side effect.  You may want to do some checking when setting or getting variables.
2. getters and setters

   In C++ they don't have a fixed name rule, you could name it whatever you want, it's just good practice to still with some convention, like [google coding style for c++](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Classes)

Answer (score 0):

This is some information I got for your question,

1. You'll have refined control of accessibility of the data members. You can implement no access, read only access or read-write access through setters/getters.
2. Functional abstraction. When you implement access to a member through a function, you then can change the implementation of the function due to future change. Only your code has to be recompiled and the world outside still remains intact.
3. You can provide some kind of checking in the getters/setters.